# Four leaf clover only growing three leaves

Tags: houseplants, lawn, growth

I found a patch of lawn with a high percentage of four leaf clover (standard white clover), carefully dug up several four leaf stems with roots, and transplanted into a pot. But all the new growth is coming in with just three leaves. What can I do to get it to grow more four leaf stems?

Side note, I did shock it by letting it dry out too much before potting, and it experienced another unfortunate drought this weekend while I was away, but otherwise it seems to be growing well and putting out new growth and a few blossoms at the same time as the undisturbed clover in the lawn.

Comment: So today it has put out a five leaf stem, so anecdotally "complain loudly and threaten to throw the whole pot out" seems to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing, probably, it was just a temporary genetic aberration. From what I've read, clover does carry a gene that gives 4 leaves, but its usually shadowed or overridden by the 3 leaf gene, and its only in certain environmental conditions that the 4 leaves might appear. Quite what those conditions are I don't know, but its possible for occasional six or five leaf versions to appear, temporarily or otherwise. Info here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-leaf_clover